# do_shortcode within a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

This may sound a little confusing but I'll try my best to explain. I've made a shortcode that grabs the content of a post (when given the id), it looks like this:

```
$post_id = $id;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$postcontent = $queried_post->post_content;
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
```

I then have another variable which puts a few things together and gets returned:

```
$finaloutput = $title . $postcontent;
```

What I want to do is be able to run shortcodes  withing `$postcontent`, so when a post is fetched any shortcodes within that post will display. I tried running `do_shortcode` on the `$postcontent` variable but it caused the page to literally not load at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your code attempt to add do_shortcode ? sounds like you had a PHP error.

Comment: It was yesterday and I haven't version controlled this but I believe it was $finaloutput = $title . do_shortcode ($postcontent); I also tried putting the do_shortcode into it's own variable so $shortcodeoutput = do_shortcode ($postcontent);

Comment: Does `$postcontent = apply_filters( 'the_content', $postcontent );` work?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with that :/ Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
add_shortcode( 'content','content_callback' );

function content_callback( $atts, $content = NULL ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'pid' => '',
    ), $atts);      

    if( ! is_int( 1 * $atts['pid'] ) )
        return "<!-- Shortcode Error: pid must be an integer -->"; 

    if(  absint( $atts['pid'] ) === get_the_ID() )
        return "<!-- Shortcode Error: pid can't be the current id -->"; 

    $queried_post = get_post( absint( $atts['pid'] ) );

    if( ! is_object( $queried_post ) )
        return "<!-- Shortcode Error: Post not found! -->";

    $postcontent = do_shortcode( $queried_post->post_content );
    $title = $queried_post->post_title;

    $finaloutput = $title . $postcontent;

    return $finaloutput;
}
```

where the shortcode is used like this:

```
[content pid="2069"]
```

where `pid` is some post ID.

Comment: Unfortunately results in the same error :/

Comment: strange, this works on my install. You should check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress. Do you get any errors in debug.log ? You could also try to deactivate your plugins and also try it on the default TwentyTwelve theme.

Comment: Currently using the default 2012 theme with no plugins - debugging still results in a browser error rather than a PHP error - perhaps I'll try on a server.

Comment: Tried on a server - no PHP error at all but won't load the page (cuts off loading at header).

Comment: ... and the error only comes up when you add the do_shortcode? What kind of shortcodes are you using in the post?

Comment: are you using the current post id in the shortcode? I did not try that (I used some external post ID), but it might give you a recursive loop.

Comment: Ah, yes - it seems to be to do with the ID being the same :) - looks like it's working now. Going to do some more testing to make sure it's robust.

Comment: I updated the code to avoid the use of the current id in the shortcode ;-)